# What technologies were used to create Smartermail by Smartertools and Action Method by Behance?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, user-interface

What technology was used to create the User Interface of "Smartermail" by Smartertools and the User Interface of "Action Method" by Behance?

They both have great user interfaces that expand to fit a full browser window, they are both very repsonsive (especially SmarterMail) and I don't believe they require a plugin?

Are these technologies suitable for ASP.NET MVC based sites?

Answer (score 2):

The forum post referenced by another responder was from over a year ago, and some things have changed since then.

Since SmarterMail 7.x, Telerik was abandoned for most of the user interface controls due to some issues with the weight of the scripts and processing time to render things.  Instead, custom versions of controls that render simpler HTML and script were developed to ensure things went quickly.  SmarterTools still uses Telerik's radEditor HTML editing control, and the DateTimePicker control in applications, however, since they have shown to be the best option.

Charting is now accomplished through the built-in .Net Charting controls that were added in Microsoft .Net 4.0.  We found then to be a suitable replacement for the Nevron Charting controls in most cases, and almost as fast.

SmarterMail does not use MVC as of version 8.x.  It could be written as such, but at this point the advantages of rewriting it to be in MVC did not yield a good enough return on investment.

jQuery is the primary method of resizing and adding visual effects, and has proven to be quite effective.  Most of the performance problems we ran into were related to resizing, so the order of operations when resizing had to be continually tuned.

ASP.Net AJAX with page methods is used to perform a "keep-alive" function on a regular basis that updates counters, signals the session is still active, and retrieves notifications from the server about new email, etc.  Many other page functions use AJAX as well to make the pages feel more responsive and to reduce the amount of data flying around.

Grady Werner (SmarterTools)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [discussion](http://forums.smartertools.com/t/25612.aspx) about the technologies used in SmarterMail:

> We use components from Telerik for the
>   Splitters, treeviews, editor, menus,
>   date/time pickers, panelbars,
>   tabstrips, and popup windows. With our
>   own custom skins and a lot of hacks
>   for efficiency. Though I think someone
>   at telerik spies on us because every
>   time we hack in an optimization, they
>   follow suit in their next version
>
> The grid is our own control. Other
>   than that we use asp.net ajax and
>   jquery and thats it.

And because your question was tagged with `asp.net-mvc-2`, you could use the same controls in your application. Telerik provide controls [specifically designed for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx). And [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) are totally server technology agnostic.